# writing posts in indian regional language (Punjabi)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-content

I am trying to create a post in [Punjabi Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punjabi_language) . But when i try to paste punjabi text into the editor , the language automatically gets converted to English. I tried using the Google Translator plugin , but that does not convert the page accurately.

Is there a way i can post articles in regional language ?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  You might like to review [ask].  Here we generally answer questions about problems developers are having with their own code.

Comment: There's nothing standard in WP that would do this.  Might there be a plugin, or even an extension to your browser that's doing it?

Comment: Do you really mean "the language automatically gets converted to English" or do you mean that the characters are converted to something that looks like a western European alphabet?

Comment: In that case only solution that I can suggest is use a virtual keyboard. Download virtual keyboad for Punjabi and type from it. http://frontype.com/keyboard/Punjabi-keyboard-layout.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to install WordPress and use it in Punjabi, there is an ongoing effort to localize WordPress into Punjabi; see https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/ The support forums in Punjabi are not yet complete: https://pan.wordpress.org/

> I tried using the Google Translator plugin, but that does not convert
>   the page accurately.

Google Translator is machine translation, not human; it won't be accurate to a native speaker. And, that's a completely separate issue than actually using WordPress in Punjabi, i.e. entering text in Punjabi in the Wordpress editor.

If you want to post Punjabi text in a WordPress site installed in another language (like English), you can paste Punjabi from Google Translate https://translate.google.com/ and have it render correctly in WordPress. (I tried this myself).

If it doesn't, something is wrong. It might be worth contacting the translation team https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/?locale=pa_IN

Comment: But that doesn't affect the content, just the interface.  The OP seems to have his content automatically translated when he pastes it.

Comment: Punjabi uses a different code-space in Unicode than ASCII does; the Punjabi localization will account for that, which is what is needed to present the Punjabi fonts. Pasting from Google Translate means nothing when the WordPress editor can't handle the code-space.

Comment: Am I being too literal when the OP says "the language automatically gets converted to English?"

Comment: @markratledge, all languages use different code space in unicode than ascii, that do no prevent me from using hebrew in non localized wordpress. Supporting a language in an editor is a browser and tinymce thing and if a ltr/ltr labguage is not not supported (which I doubt) its sounds like a good case for opening a ticket. Use case where localization is impossible - I want to post a Punjabi quote in my english blog.

Comment: You're right; should be able to paste into a non-localized install without issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install google input language (punjabi). Once you learn to type punjabi through google input language method, it is quite easy, just type ,copy your content and paste any where on webpage (post editing) without going through messy convert language softwares. Best thing is open wordpad, notepad or any text page, type your content in punjabi through google input language (punjabi), and paste anywhere. but If you go on typing punjabi content using amar lipi, anmol,or satluj font and paste it as it is, problem remains unsolved. get google input language (punjabi) through below given link, 
http://www.google.co.in/inputtools/windows/

select punjabi language, after installing, open language keyboard in your PC control panel, select google input language, and show this on desktop, then you would see a language bar on your desktop screen, chose Punjabi, and start typing, thats all entire procedure you need to follow.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I copy and paste from Microsoft Word 2013, the characters get changed to English alphabet ( not translated ). 
So I am copying and pasting from OpenOffice, it works cool. Also copying text from Google translate works fine. So I would suggest you to open your text files in OpenOffice first and then copy from there.